# How to generate random boolean value in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Im writing a database for some kind of university and there is a table named

> Contact_Assign
>   Its parameters are:

```
Is_Instructor       UD_BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
Is_TeacherAssistant UD_BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
Is_Student          UD_BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
Registration_ID     UD_ID      NOT NULL,
Contact_ID          UD_ID      NOT NULL,
```

now I want to insert dummy data in this table but I have no idea how can I do this for the boolean parameters.

PS. UD_BOOLEAN is

```
CREATE TYPE UD_BOOLEAN FROM BIT
```

any idea how?

Comment: I highly recommend just using BIT. What do you get by using UD_BOOLEAN except - if you later decide to change the name, change the underlying type or change between NULL / NOT NULL - a whole bunch of headache? Have you ever tried to change anything about an alias type after it has its tentacles into all of your objects? This may seem like a clever choice now, but having learned the hard way, I can promise you it is no such thing.

Comment: I agree with @AaronBertrand. CLR UDTs can be quite useful (though still a real pain to update once deployed) but SQL UDTs are really pretty useless. See [T-SQL UDTs. (Huh!) What are they good for?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2010/08/25/t-sql-udts-what-are-they-good-for.aspx) for some discussion on this.

Comment: Also [Bad habits to kick : using alias types](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types.aspx) - lots of good comments there too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are only generating one row, you could use something as simple as:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(RAND(),0) AS BIT)
```

However, if you are generating more than one row, `RAND()` will evaluate to the same value for every row, so please see [Martin Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20597328/61305).

Comment: Uh, no, this isn't good. `SELECT TOP (1000) CAST(ROUND(RAND(),0) AS BIT) FROM sys.all_columns;` That doesn't seem very random to me. Why not? Because `RAND()` is only ever evaluated once as either a 1 or 0, and that value persists across every single row. This only has any chance of ever working if you generate every row one at a time - and you shouldn't ever do that, either.

Comment: I was tempted to delete this answer for exactly that reason. When I thought about it more I realised this was a poor solution. Shame its been accepted and not @MartinSmith answer

Comment: You can also get this solution to work with multiple rows by doing trhe following: `CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())),0) AS BIT)`

Answer (score 31):

You can use

```
CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) % 2
```

The advantages over `RAND` are that it is stronger cryptographically (you may not care) and that if inserting multiple rows it is re-evaluated for each row.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
  B1 BIT,
  B2 BIT);

INSERT INTO @T
SELECT TOP 10 CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1)%2,
              CAST(ROUND(RAND(), 0) AS BIT)
FROM   master..spt_values

SELECT *
FROM   @T
```

would give the same value in all rows for the second column

Comment: +1 this is the right answer, not anything involving `RAND()`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a different value for the second column, you can use `newid()`.  Here is an example:

```
select cast((case when left(newid(), 1) between '0' and '7' then 1 else 0 end) as bit)
```

You would only need `newid()` if you were inserting more than one row in a single statement.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that makes use of `NEWID()`:

```
select ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 2
```